# Two addresses on one NIC, today's ubuntu update has broken it

Tags: networking, dns, dhcp

I'm running Ubuntu 16.04 on a NUC to manage my home and work networks. The single NIC in the NUC is allocated two IP addresses, one in each network, by the following lines in `/etc/network/interfaces`:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
#1st is home
auto enp3s0
iface enp3s0 inet static
  address 192.168.0.1
  netmask 255.255.255.0
  gateway 192.168.0.254 # huawei modem
  dns-search homenet
#2nd is work vpn
auto enp3s0:1
iface enp3s0:1 inet static
  address 172.16.9.1
  netmask 255.255.255.240
  gateway 172.16.9.1
  dns-search xx.yy.xx.com
```

`ifconfig` used to show me both inet addresses, `192.168.0.1` and `172.16.9.1`, but since running the offered ubuntu updates today it now only shows the first. Machines in the work subnet cannot see each other or the outside network because IP address `172.16.9.1` is unreachable.

Something must have changed but I don't know what or how to fix it.

This machine is running `isc-dhcp-server` to allocate IP addresses in both the home and work networks, and `bind9` to do DNS lookups for the home network. When it's working properly DNS for the work machines is managed by the VPN.

I am not using the graphical Network Manager.

Any ideas what I could look at to get this working again?

**UPDATE**:
I've subsequently seen a line in `boot.log` that wasn't there in the past:

```
Failed to start Raise network interfaces.
See 'systemctl status networking.service' for details.
```

So I did that. and I can see the following message 4 times:

```
ifup[670]: Another app is currently holding the xtables lock.
   Perhaps you want to use the -w option?
```

Within `/etc/network` I have an `if-pre-up.d/iptables` script which calls the system `iptables` command five times. I guess this is where the error is coming from - but it has worked reliably until today's update. While I could put `-w` on all these lines I suspect that I would be treating a symptom rather than addressing the real cause - which I still haven't identified.

**UPDATE 2**:
Originally I had thought that the five calls to `iptables` in my script had produced four `xtables lock` errors. What I have discovered is that my script is actually called four times: once for each interface (`lo`, `enp3s0`, and `enp3s0:1`) and once with an `$IFACE` value of `--all`. The invocations for `--all` and `enp3s0` are run simultaneously and one is blocking the other.

I can't find anything in the changelogs but I'd hazard a guess that running this script for IFACE=--all is perhaps the underlying cause of the problem I am having.

Thanks in advance

Cheers,
T

Comment: Wondering if the upgrade over-wrote the contents of /etc/network/interfaces or whatever file you edited to create the VPN virtual network.  Shouldn't have unless you created it in a file that the release notes said would get clobbered.

Comment: I've found a FAILED entry in the boot.log:

    Failed to start Raise network interfaces
    See 'systemctl status networking.service' for details

Checking there I can see lots of lines which all repeat

    Another app is currently holding the xtables lock. Perhaps you want to use the -w option?

This is new.

Comment: Than add it to your question ;) I thought is has to be `dns-nameservers blabla` instead of `dns-search` and it should be IPs I guess .. because if you still don't have DNS resolving .. how should the interfaces conf know who xx.yy.zz.com is?

Comment: Well I know next to nothing about networking, but as I understand it the dns-search lines are there so that if a machine in the 192.168.x subnet refers to "fred" and fred is as yet unknown, the service will try fred.homenet, while if a machine in the 172.16.x subnet does the same the service will first look for fred.xx.yy.zz.com.
It all used to work :-)

Comment: The `/etc/network/interfaces` file is the same as my backup copy, while the `/etc/network/interfaces.d` directory is empty, as it was before. So it doesn't seem to have changed anything there.

Comment: You could move the script out of the /etc/network startup sequence and see if that fixes your VPN interface.  Then you'll know that you have an iptables issue to look at.

Comment: See https://serverfault.com/questions/805718/iptables-another-app-is-currently-holding-the-xtables-lock