# Where can I find the change notices for previously installed updates?

Tags: updates, update-manager

When the software updater offers to update my installation I can select any of the proffered updates and view details of the changes which will be made. Is there a repository anywhere of the change descriptions for previously installed updates?

Last week I did an "install now" without drilling down into the changes first and it broke my network, so I'd like to review what was installed and see exactly what change was responsible. That way I hope to fix my network config properly instead of relying on the hack that I have used in the meantime.

Comment: probably better to fix the problem rather then trying to review cangelogs and undo updates. what "hack" are you using ?

Comment: Sorry I was unclear. I don't want to undo the update, I want to know what changed so that I can apply the proper fix to my config. At the moment I have inserted a pause into any script which calls `iptables`, because since the last software update `iptables` is reporting that `xtables` is locked. But that is unlikely to be the appropriate fix.

Comment: Can you post the exact error message you are getting ? pastebin your iptables rules as well.

Comment: Probably better to give you a link to the relevant question, as this one related to the changelogs and it's now been answered.
I raised my error here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/925186/two-addresses-on-one-nic-todays-ubuntu-update-has-broken-it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find out what you installed when by looking at the file `/var/log/apt/history.log*`, then for each package you suspect, use `apt-get changelog <packagename>` to retrieve the changelog.